# mysql highcharts php rtg

Tags: php, mysql, sql, highcharts

First I want to say that I have looked at stackoverflow and highcharts forum, but have not been able to find a answer to my question, so I hope some kind soul can provide me with a working example of my problem.

I am trying to create a spline chart (not auto updating) from data in a mysql db created by rtg (rtg.sourceforge.net)

I am not a programmer, so please bear with me, for not creating clean/proper code (this includes copy/paste from several other sources).

There is 3 tables id (INT) , dtime (DATETIME) and counter (BIGINT) with the following sample:

```
1   2012-03-05 17:49:06 16991
2   2012-03-05 17:50:06 3774
3   2012-03-05 17:50:06 1272
```

(1,2,3 is the interface names)

I am trying to create with a chart that will show traffic for the last hour.

This is the content of my data.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","XXXXXXXX");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("rtg", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ifInOctets_1 ORDER BY dtime DESC LIMIT 0,60");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['dtime'] . "\t" . $row['counter']. "\n";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The output from data.php is in the following format:

```
2012-03-05 20:53:31 245891 2012-03-05 20:53:31  8530 2012-03-05 20:53:31    6424577
```

rtg is polling 3 times pr min, so this results in 180 output "fields" from the above sql query.

This is the content of my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 


<title>Chart 1 Hour</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themes/gray.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var chart;
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                var options = {
                                        chart: {
                                                renderTo: 'container',
                                                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                                                marginRight: 130,
                                                marginBottom: 25
                                        },
                                        credits: {
                                           enabled: false
                                        },
                                        title: {
                                                text: 'Bits',
                                                x: -20 //center
                                        },
                                        subtitle: {
                                                text: '',
                                                x: -20
                                        },
                                        xAxis: {
                                                type: 'datetime',
                                                tickInterval: 3600 * 1000, // one hour
                                                tickWidth: 0,
                                                gridLineWidth: 1,
                                                labels: {
                                                        align: 'center',
                                                        x: -3,
                                                        y: 20,
                                                        formatter: function() {
                                                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', this.value);
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        },
                                        yAxis: {
                                                title: {
                                                        text: 'Bits'
                                                },
                                                plotLines: [{
                                                        value: 0,
                                                        width: 1,
                                                        color: '#808080'
                                                }]
                                        },
                                        tooltip: {
                                                formatter: function() {
                                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y%m%d%H%M%S', this.x-(1000*3600)) +'-'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.x) +': <b>'+ this.y + '</b>';
                                                }
                                        },
                                        legend: {
                                                layout: 'vertical',
                                                align: 'right',
                                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                                x: -10,
                                                y: 100,
                                                borderWidth: 0
                                        },
                                        series: [{
                                                name: 'BlaBla'
                                        }]
                                }
                                // Load data asynchronously using jQuery. On success, add the data
                                // to the options and initiate the chart.
                                // This data is obtained by exporting a GA custom report to TSV.
                                // http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
                                jQuery.get('data.php', null, function(tsv) {
                                        var lines = [];
                                        traffic = [];
                                        try {
                                                // split the data return into lines and parse them
                                                tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                                                jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                                                        line = line.split(/\t/);
                                                        date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                                                        traffic.push([
                                                                date,
                                                                parseInt(line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)
                                                        ]);
                                                });
                                        } catch (e) {  }
                                        options.series[0].data = traffic;
                                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                                });
                        });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width: 960px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code it looks like all the data is cramped to the left side of the chart.
(Sorry could not post a screenshot, first time user.)

Since highcharts needs the the date + time in miliseconds, I have tried (among several other sql select statements) to change the Highcharts.dateFormat but without any luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your return date to return as the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

So `SELECT * FROM ifInOctets_1 ORDER BY dtime DESC LIMIT 0,60` would become:

`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dtime)*1000,counter FROM ifInOctets_1 ORDER BY dtime DESC LIMIT 0,60"

That way you have the correct timestamp in ms value that highcharts expects.